# Howto use invokedynamic with Jasmin?

Tags: jvm, jasmin, invokedynamic

[Here](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/xt.html) it says:

```
Since 2.1 :
[..]
added the invokedynamic instruction
```

Thus I suppose that it is possible to write instruction code containing invokedynamics with jasmin. However I could not find any documentation on the jasmin syntax and I just figured out how to use invokedynamic to get VerifyErrors with Jasmin, but not how to create a working example.

How is this instruction correctly used in Jasmin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `invokedynamic` bytecode should refer to a corresponding call site specifier [(JVMS 6.5)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokedynamic) which is actually a constant pool entry of `CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic` type [(JVMS  4.4.10)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.10).

Jasmin (http://jasmin.sourceforge.net) does not support `CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic`, but Sable/jasmin does. Though using `invokedynamic` in hand-written assembly is ungrateful job.

Here is an example of dynamic method that returns a reference to `System.out`:

```
.class public HelloWorld
.super java/lang/Object

.method public <init>()V
   aload_0
   invokespecial java/lang/Object/<init>()V
   return
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   .limit stack 2
   .limit locals 1

   invokedynamic "getPrintStream" ()Ljava/io/PrintStream; HelloWorld/bootstrap(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;()
   ldc "Hello, world"
   invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V

   return
.end method

.method private static bootstrap(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
   .limit stack 6
   .limit locals 3

   new java/lang/invoke/ConstantCallSite
   dup

   aload_0
   ldc java/lang/System
   ldc "out"
   ldc java/io/PrintStream
   invokevirtual java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup/findStaticGetter(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;

   invokespecial java/lang/invoke/ConstantCallSite/<init>(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;)V

   areturn
.end method
```

Comment: Did you test the code? Did it work for you? Because sable/jasmin seems to end up in an infinite loop on my machine and eventually fails with an OutOfMemoryError... *debugging*...

Comment: After debugging, I figured that I need to append a linefeed at the end of the file and indeed, that fixed the OutOfMemoryError... *facepalm*. Anyhow, thanks for your input :-).