# Since all Java compiles to bytecode, why would you ever get an UnsupportedClassVersionError?

Tags: java, unsupported-class-version

I know that `UnsupportedClassVersionError` happens when trying to run code compiled with newer versions of the JDK, such as Java 1.7 on a Java 1.6 JDK.

I don't understand why this would happen. The compiled code is bytecode and, as I understand bytecode, it is a very simple and minimal version of the code.

For example Java's 8 lambdas are just methods in the byte code, since methods are supported from JDK 1.0 there should not be a problem running code compiled in JDK 8 on JDK 1.

What changes to later Java versions would preclude a Java class compiled with a newer JDK from running on an older JDK?

Thanks!

Comment: `Java's 8 lambdas are just methods in the byte code` No, that's a gross oversimplification.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I spent several months working on a JVM implementation and I actually don't have a good understanding of why this wouldn't work. If you could provide an answer, I'd love to see what specifically would go wrong.

Comment: @templatetypedef You're probably much more qualified than I am with that kind of background. For lambdas though, they depend on classes that were only added in Java 8. Obviously a lower version JRE could not use them.

Comment: @templatetypedef, there is a [presentation from Oracle](http://wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/images/7/7b/Goetz-jvmls-lambda.pdf) on how they did this any why. They actually used the `invokedynamic` instruction from Java 7.

Comment: There are a couple bytecode changes listed at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html

Comment: So, is this error occurs because of code using internal classes that are new to a jdk ?
For example if I have class A in JDK 7 and I write code that runs fine on JDK 6 but uses that class A I'l get the UnsupportedClassVersionError although its just a class not found error ?

Comment: @DavidLimkys And new op-codes, Java pre-7 didn't have `invokedynamic`; see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23856770/2970947)

Comment: @DavidLimkys My *guess* (I have nothing to back this up) is that the bytecode specifies its compile-time version, so you'll get the error automatically if you try to use the wrong JVM, even if you don't make use of any classes that had that changed. That, or it maintains a "minimum version" for new or changed functionality in each class. It doesn't have to be a class-not-found error: there could be new methods or implementations that are incompatible with other versions.

Comment: @DavidLimkys No, that would be a different problem. Each Java .class file has a header stating the bytecode version. If that check fails you get that exception. (For example before Java5 there were no annotations, with Java 8 you can use annotations on other places too.)

Comment: So, If I have a jar that was compiled on JDK 7 but uses none of those new features, then it should run with out a problem on older JDK such as 6.

Alright all of this does make sense, I would still love a complete explanation tough, if someone would be so kind :)

Comment: You get an UnsupportedClassVersionError because the class contains a version number greater than the max version supported by the JVM.  It's (almost) that simple.  In general, the compiler will make a weak attempt to set the class version no higher than necessary, but it errs on the side of safety.  (The statement by @DavidLimkys directly above is sorta correct, but some changes such as the addition of the StackMapTable you get "for free" unless you explicitly say to compile for an earlier version.)

Comment: @DavidLimkys Still no: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file major version 51 (Java 7) vs. version 50 (Java 6), though you can use backporting tools (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_backporting_tools) or just compile accordingly.

Comment: @HotLicks I do not understand you, if the .class files contain the ver number, does that mean that even if the code technically works in the older jdk it wont run on it was signed by the newer one ?
That sounds really bad, why limit java developers like that, if the code can run on jdk 6 why not allow it just because it was compiled under jdk 7?

Comment: That's what it means.  You can always tell javac to target a certain JVM level, but if you leave it to its own devices you have no guarantee that something compiled on version X will run on X-1.