# When is invokedynamic actually useful (besides lazy constants)?

Tags: dynamic, jvm, invokedynamic

## TL;DR

Please provide a piece of code written in some well known dynamic language (e.g. JavaScript) and how that code would look like in Java bytecode using invokedynamic and explain why the usage of invokedynamic is a step forward here.

## Background

I have googled and read quite a lot about the not-that-new-anymore invokedynamic instruction which everyone on the internet agrees on that it will help speed dynamic languages on the JVM. [Thanks to stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23856770/327301) I managed to get my own bytecode instructions with Sable/Jasmin to run.

I have understood that invokedynamic is useful for lazy constants and I also think that I understood how [the OpenJDK takes advantage of invokedynamic for lambdas](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html).

Oracle has [a small example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/multiple-language-support.html#challenges), but as far as I can tell the usage of invokedynamic in this case defeats the purpose as the example for "adder" could much simpler, faster and with roughly the same effect expressed with the following bytecode:

```
aload whereeverAIs
checkcast java/lang/Integer
aload whereeverBIs
checkcast java/lang/Integer
invokestatic IntegerOps/adder(Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Integer;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
```

because for some reason Oracle's bootstrap method knows that both arguments are integers anyway. They even "admit" that:

> [..]it assumes that the arguments [..] will be Integer objects. A bootstrap method requires additional code to properly link invokedynamic [..] if the parameters of the bootstrap method (in this example, callerClass, dynMethodName, and dynMethodType) vary.

Well yes, and without that interesing "additional code" there is no point in using invokedynamic here, is there?

So after that and a couple of further Javadoc and Blog entries I think that I have a pretty good grasp on how to use invokedynamic as a poor replacement when invokestatic/invokevirtual/invokevirtual or getfield would work just as well.

Now I am curious how to actually apply the invokedynamic instruction to a real world usecase so that it actually is some improvements over what we could with "traditional" invocations (except lazy constants, I got those...).

Answer (score 8):

Actually, lazy operations are the main advantage of `invokedynamic` if you take the term “lazy creation” broadly. E.g., the lambda creation feature of Java 8 is a kind of lazy creation that includes the possibility that the actual class containing the code that will be finally invoked by the `invokedynamic` instruction doesn’t even exist prior to the execution of that instruction.

This can be projected to all kind of scripting languages delivering code in a different form than Java bytecode (might be even in source code). Here, the code may be compiled right before the first invocation of a method and remains linked afterwards. But it may even become unlinked if the scripting language supports redefinition of methods. This uses the second important feature of `invokedynamic`, to allow mutable `CallSite`s which may be changed afterwards while supporting maximal performance when being invoked frequently without redefinition.

This possibility to change an `invokedynamic` target afterwards allows another option, linking to an interpreted execution on the first invocation, counting the number of executions and compiling the code only after exceeding a threshold (and relinking to the compiled code then).

---

Regarding dynamic method dispatch based on a runtime instance, it’s clear that `invokedynamic` can’t elide the dispatch algorithm. But if you detect at runtime that a particular call-site will always call the method of the same concrete type you may relink the `CallSite` to an optimized code which will do a short check if the target is that expected type and performs the optimized action then but branches to the generic code performing the full dynamic dispatch only if that test fails. The implementation may even de-optimize such a call-site if it detects that the fast path check failed a certain number of times.

This is close to how `invokevirtual` and `invokeinterface` are optimized internally in the JVM as for these it’s also the case that most of these instructions are called on the same concrete type. So with `invokedynamic` you can use the same technique for arbitrary lookup algorithms.

---

But if you want an entirely different use case, you can use `invokedynamic` to implement `friend` semantics which are not supported by the standard access modifier rules. Suppose you have a class `A` and `B` which are meant to have such a `friend` relationship in that `A` is allowed to invoke `private` methods of `B`. Then all these invocations may be encoded as `invokedynamic` instructions with the desired name and signature and pointing to a `public` bootstrap method in `B` which may look like this:

```
public static CallSite bootStrap(Lookup l, String name, MethodType type)
    throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException {
    if(l.lookupClass()!=A.class || (l.lookupModes()&0xf)!=0xf)
      throw new SecurityException("unprivileged caller");
    l=MethodHandles.lookup();
    return new ConstantCallSite(l.findStatic(B.class, name, type));
}
```

It first verifies that the provided `Lookup` object has full access to `A` as only `A` is capable of constructing such an object. So sneaky attempts of wrong callers are sorted out at this place. Then it uses a `Lookup` object having full access to `B` to complete the linkage. So, each of these `invokedynamic` instructions is permanently linked to the matching `private` method of `B` after the first invocation, running at the same speed as ordinary invocations afterwards.

Comment: regarding your last snippet, I think you can achieve the same thing by using `StackWalker::getCallerClass` and `privateLookupIn`, provided there is at least java-9.

Comment: @Eugene this example was written before Java 9 existed. But anyway, `privateLookupIn` requires the target class to be in the same module or opened to the other module for Reflection. In contrast, the snippet above allows to grant specific access to a specific artifact without sacrificing any other encapsulation, as far as it exists.

Comment: I understand that, it still feels weird? that you do `l=MethodHandles.lookup();` and then wrap that in publicly exposed `CallSite`. I am not saying this is wrong, it just feels somehow weird to me, `privateLookUpIn` at least gives me the proper understanding of what is going on without surprises. It might totally be me to blame here

Comment: @Eugene first, the method does not expose to the public, as it only returns a `CallSite` to verified callers. Second, the `CallSite` does not wrap a lookup object at all; it only encapsulates a particular `MethodHandle`. Further, this method is inside `B`, willingly providing  access to itself to `A`. I don’t know, what alternative you have in mind. When `A` uses `privateLookUpIn` to get access to `B`, the class `B` has no control over it at all.

Comment: that makes perfect sense, thank you for the follow-up.