# How to restrict the visibility/accessibility of a method to sub-package in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to understand if we have any option in Java 8 to restrict the visibility/accessibility of a method to sub-package?

For example, if I've a method print() of class A in a package abc. Now, how can i restrict that method to be accessible only in abc's sub-packages like abc.def or abc.def.ijk etc.

Comment: you can't. at times, I really want this feature

Comment: Java, as a language, is not aware of *subpackages*. There is no such thing to the language. Package `foo` and `foo.bar` are two completely unrelated and different packages.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such feature in the language. One option to achieve this, is to encapsulate the action into a public type and carefully publish it to the intended package. E.g.

```
package abc;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

import abc.def.B;
import java.lang.Objects;

public class A {
    public static Consumer<A> getPrintAccess(B.AccessToken token) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(token);
        return A::print;
    }

    private void print() {
        System.out.println("privileged action");
    }
}
```

```
package abc.def;

import abc.A;

public class B {
    public static class AccessToken {
        /* non-public */ AccessToken() {}
    }

    void someMethod(A object) {
        A.getPrintAccess(new AccessToken()).accept(object);
    }
}
```

While the method `getPrintAccess` is publicly visible, it will grant access only to code capable of instantiating `abc.def.B.AccessToken`. Since its constructor is package-private, only code in package `abc.def` can do that. Of course, code in that package must not hand out an instance of `AccessToken` to untrusted code.

Comment: this is rather ingenious, though it will work per-package only, not in sub-packages. still very interesting

Comment: @Eugene well, since Java has no sub-packages, you have to treat every package as distinct. An alternative would be to check the caller class, which allows to test against a list or check the beginning of the package name, but the efficient standard way to check it has been added in Java 9. The last part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27451057/2711488) describes a similar concept on the bytecode level, using `invokedynamic` to invoke the `friend` method.

Comment: thanks @Holger for the example, looks really interesting pattern to learn. i'll give a try

Comment: @Holger it seems there is a problem with this approach, since the 'AccessToken' is package private, we can't get access to this constructor from another class of another sub-package like 'abc.xyz'

Comment: @Raj that’s what Eugene and I discussed above, it requires a distinct token for every package you want to support. Java’s packages aren’t hierarchical, regardless of what the directory structure or our intuition tells us. So from Java’s point of view, `abc.def`  and `abc.xyz` are entirely unrelated, just like `foo` and `bar` are. The alternative would be to check the caller, but [the official solution](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.html#getCallerClass()) requires Java 9.

Comment: sure, Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I thought about `StackWalker` too, but those would be runtime solutions only. this one on the other hand is a compile time, which is lovely.

Comment: @Eugene well, you can dodge the restriction at compile-time by passing `null`, which is the reason why there is an explicit runtime check. But yes, this still helps becoming aware at compile-time that you are probably trying to defeat the method’s purpose when you have to pass `null` because you don’t have access to an appropriate argument. Then, getting a `NullPointerException` for passing `null` doesn’t come at a surprise.